# How to deactivate my plugin upon deactivation of NextGen

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, deactivation

i'm writing this plugin and i need to deactivate it when NextGen is deactivated:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Plugin Name
Description: Description
Version: 1.0
Author: Author
Author URI: Author URI
*/

// ini_set( "display_errors", 0);

global $nextgenUrl;
$nextgenUrl = str_replace('/','\\',WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'nextgen-gallery\nggallery.php');

register_deactivation_hook( $nextgenUrl , 'disattiva' );

[... other code ...]

function disattiva(){
    deactivate_plugins(__FILE__);
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea? :(

I've also used these urls:

```
$nextgenUrl = 'nextgen-gallery\nggallery.php';
$nextgenUrl = '/nextgen-gallery/nggallery.php';
```

and still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to actually check `is_plugin_active`.  I would use something more like this, shamelessly stolen and modified from [here](http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/481/wordpress-plugin-dependency-programming):

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'dependentplugin_activate' );

function dependentplugin_activate()
{
  require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

  if ( is_plugin_active( 'nextgen-gallery/nggallery.php' ) )
  {
    require_once ( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/nextgen-gallery/nggallery.php' );
  }
  else
  {
     // deactivate dependent plugin
    deactivate_plugins( __FILE__);
    //   throw new Exception('Requires another plugin!');
   //  exit();
    exit ('Requires another plugin!');
   }
}
```

Edit: just realize you're looking for deactivate, not activate.  Still, maybe this will get your brain working in the right direction.

Comment: I did it this way
`register_deactivation_hook( $nextgenUrl , 'disattiva' );

function disattiva(){
 require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
 deactivate_plugins( __FILE__);
}`

still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this with $_GET['action']

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'deactivate')
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do you know that it is the **NextGen Gallery Plugin** being deactivated, and not some other Plugin?

Comment: @ChipBennett `$_GET['plugin']` holds the name.